# My json "key" have "String" type value. How to identify whether received string has "link" or "simple string"?

Tags: java, android, json

I have a json object with a "thumbnail" key. This key can have one of the two possible values:

Either a link to a thumbnail of an image

```
{
 "thumbnail":  
 "http://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/DACtraltHm3czpqyUO_g50LpPOeswwEa8Spj-9Lvt-U.jpg"
}
```

or a simple string

```
{"thumbnail": "self"}
```

My question is how can I distinguish whether the value is a "link" or a "simple word"?

Comment: chcek if string has 'http' than its link otherwise word

Comment: I have tried to restate your question in a more clear way. Also added proper code formatting. This greatly helps others to read and understand your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check it in any of the following ways:

**1.** Use UrlValidator class from [commons-validator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/) library.

```
org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator.getInstance().isValid(url);
```

**2.** If you want to avoid using an external library then write a utility method to check it:

```
public static boolean isValidUrl(final String url) {
    try {
        new URL(url);
        return true;
    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
        // IGNORE
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you want to do it on Android you could simply get away by using

```
android.webkit.URLUtil.isHttpUrl(url)
```